# Issues with my grading system

Tags: php, mysql

This part of my code is used to award a grade to a student score whenever i request a student semester result (Course Scores). But, only a particular grade is awarded to all the scores, most times the last result that was uploaded into the students database is awarded to all the scores. When i added  period to the grade i.e

```
  $grade .= 'A';
  $grade .= 'B';
  $grade .= 'C';
  $grade .= 'D';
  $grade .= 'E';
```

all the grades were repeated in each column. So assuming a particular student took 6 courses in a semester and had a total of

```
  3 A's , 2 B's , 1 C
```

all the 6 grades were repeated on each row for the six courses.

I'll be delighted to show othe parts of the code.
Thank you for you time and patience.

```
   while ($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc               ($query8)) {
            if ($row8['score'] >= 70) {
              $grade = 'A';
           }
            elseif ($row8['score'] >= 60) {
            $grade = 'B';
            }elseif ($row8['score'] >= 50) {
            $grade = 'C';
            }elseif ($row8['score'] >= 45) {
            $grade = 'D';
            }elseif($row8['score'] >= 40) {
            $grade = 'E';
            }else{
            $grade = 'F';
            }   
            }
```

This is the query (query8) the looks up the score for the student semester courses.

```
        $query8 = mysql_query("SELECT  m.          score 
  FROM    maintable AS m  
  INNER JOIN students AS s ON
  m.matric_no = s.matric_no
  INNER JOIN courses AS c ON 
   m.course_code = c.course_code
  WHERE m.matric_no = '".$matric_no."'
 AND m.level = '".$level."'") 
 or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: What school offers an `E` grade?

Comment: `$query8` is definitely important for knowing what is going on. It sounds like your `JOIN` is confidently doing a `CROSS JOIN`, which returns all combinations.

Comment: @guvante... What other part of the code should i provide?
....
Adam my school does.

Comment: show as much as you can. All of it would be great.

Comment: @jay i have updated the question, and added the query that requires the scores from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to store result in array... when any loop logic is use...do like this

```
$arr = array();
while ($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc               ($query8)) {
            if ($row8['score'] >= 70) {
              $grade = 'A';
           }
            elseif ($row8['score'] >= 60) {
            $grade = 'B';
            }elseif ($row8['score'] >= 50) {
            $grade = 'C';
            }elseif ($row8['score'] >= 45) {
            $grade = 'D';
            }elseif($row8['score'] >= 40) {
            $grade = 'E';
            }else{
            $grade = 'F';
            }

            $arr[$row8['score']] = $grade; 
            }
```

now from $arr you can retrieve the results what you get...
thanks

Comment: I added the array but i still got the same answer. Thanks

Comment: see the logic is perfect... may be problem with data retrieve... check.. http://snippi.com/s/a1eq71x

Comment: Thanks a million. Could the query i'm using to call the data be a problem?

    http://pastebin.com/s7QwCC3e

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You never do anything with $grade in the loop other than set it to A/B/C/D/E/F.  So whatever value the last score has will determine the final value of $grade.  Where do you apply the value of $grade to something else?

It looks like the last line of the loop, after all the if statements, should be something like this:

```
 do_something_with_grade($grade);
```